# Hiding / Setting display none on element using parentElement.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to hide a button that creates a new element after being clicked (to then be replaced by a delete), but i seem to be unable to change the display to "none" when i try to target the same element using the parentElement and then getting the elements by classname.

The reason i want to do it this way is to make the other element visible the same way, but it's outside of the scope of the issue i'm having right now.

I entered an example of my issue below.

```js
let template = '<div><button onclick="createNewElement(this)" class="js-create-button">+</button> </div>'


function createNewElement(e){
  e.parentElement.parentElement.innerHTML += template; // Creating new button using the template
  let a = document.getElementsByClassName("js-create-button")[0];  // Getting the element using document
  let b = e.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("js-create-button")[0];  // Getting the element using a parent element (this is the line that's causing issues)
  console.log(a);  // Both logs return the correct element, but only the first one works when i change the styling
  console.log(b);
  a.style.background = "red";
  b.style.background = "blue";
}
```

```html
<body>
  
<div>
  <div>    
    <button onclick="createNewElement(this)" class="js-create-button">+
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

In the example i changed the style to make it easier to see what's not working. The style should turn to blue, instead of red, and that goes for all the created elements after the first one too.

It somehow seems like the element that's returned is a "copy" of the original, so changing it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `e.parentElement.parentElement.innerHTML += template`, the context to the actual content of `e.parentElement.parentElement` is being lost.

Doing it this way will preserve the context

```js
let template = '<div><button onclick="createNewElement(this)" class="js-create-button 22">+</button> </div>'


function createNewElement(e) {
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.innerHTML = template

  e.parentElement.parentElement.append(newDiv.firstElementChild); // Creating new button using the template
  let a = document.getElementsByClassName("js-create-button")[0]; // Getting the element using document
  let b = e.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("js-create-button")[0]; // Getting the element using a parent element
  console.log(a); // Both logs return the correct element now
  console.log(b);
  a.style.background = "red";
  b.style.background = "blue";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <button onclick="createNewElement(this)" class="js-create-button">+
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be the problem, putting the += template at the end of the function works as well. The only thing i'm still not getting tho is why it does find back the element, yet one can't change it. I would think that if the context changed, it wouldn't find anything since it doesn't 'exist' anymore.